# ListView doesn't update when change SelectedIndex?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm using ListView as following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single"    Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        ..................
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource SettingScrollViewer}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF4B7E89"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource IpCameraTabSelectedListViewItemBrush}">

                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There are 2 problems with above code:

1. When I change myListView.SelectedIndex by code, the highlight item is not changed.
2. When I click on any button (myListView lost focus), the current SelectedItem is no longer highlight.

Someone can help me fix these bugs!

Many thanks,

T&T

Comment: Without applying ItemTemplate for ListView, your style working fine on the scenarios 1 and 2 you mentioned here. (Assuming IpCameraTabSelectedListViewItemBrush having proper brush value).

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use my own style for special application, please show me where in my code raised these issue?